# Change Osmand map to 2D-view

Tags: maps, mobile-apps, gps-navigation, software

I recently installed [osmand](https://osmand.net/) on my iPhone to use it for travelling. Unfortunately, an isometric/3D view of the map appeared. I want to change it to an ordinary 2D view. Does someone know how to do this? So far, I haven't found anything which describes how this can be done.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not tech support for apps even if those apps are used during travel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change to 2D view:

1. Click on the world icon in the top-right
2. Change the map type to *OsmAnd*
3. Go back to your map
4. If it is in 3D view still tap the blue locator button in the bottom-right till it changed the view